# Chrome extension to show a contextual menu if a specific url tab is open anywhere

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote a contextual menu-based Chrome extension. It allows me to save a music track being played by the radio as a favorite. I want this menu item to be available only when a tab with a specific matching URL of the radio player is open **anywhere** (doesn't have to be `active` or `currentWindow`). Obviously, the menu item should also be hidden from the menu when this radio player has closed.

`documentUrlPatterns` on a menu item doesn't work that way - it only shows the item on the matching pages. My goal is to be able to save the favorite without having to switch to the radio tab first.

My guess is that I should listen to `tabs.onCreated`/`onUpdated`/`onRemoved` with the player's url. Perhaps also to `onReplaced`. But is there a better, more "lazy" way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API with event filters for the URL. Event filters are registered inside Chrome itself so it wakes up the background script with `"persistent": false` only when the filter is matching. Note that filters use different syntax, not like normal matching patterns, as you can see in the example below and in each event's [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted).

```js
const filters = {
  url: [{
    hostEquals: 'www.example.com',
    queryContains: 'foo=bar',
  }]
};
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(onNavigation, filters);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onNavigation, filters);
chrome.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated.addListener(onNavigation, filters);

function onNavigation(info) {
  console.log(info);
  // modify your context menu here
}
```

manifest.json's should of course have `"permissions": ["webNavigation"]`

Comment: Yeah, kind of what I was after. Now I got to discover the annoyances of context menu API :) Thanks for the hint.